# Iphone play songs in my app

Tags: iphone

I want to play songs in my iPhone application but they should be coming from iTunes in my phone, is this possible ? any help?

Comment: This was real easy to find in the Apple iOS documentation. First search before you ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, I would start by [reading the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765).